# How does a dielectric interact with a laser beam?

Tags: optics, laser, dielectric

A nano-ball made of latex, which is insulating, has no net electrical charge, and is much smaller than the wavelength of the light. The ball is compact, homogeneous with spherical shape. It has relative dielectric constant.

My question is: If the nano-ball is placed into a well focused, polarized laser beam, how will this nano ball interact with the laser beam?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since the size of the spherical particle is much smaller than the wavelength of the light, you can use quasielectrostatic approximation, giving a relation $\underline{P} = \alpha_e * \underline{E_0}$, where $\underline{P}$ is the induced dipole moment, $\alpha_e$ is the electric polarizability and $\underline{E_0}$ is the incident electric field.

A typical electric polarizability for a spherical object under Quasistatic approximation is: $\alpha_e = 3 V \epsilon_0 \frac{\epsilon - \epsilon_0}{\epsilon - 2 \epsilon_0}$, where $V$ is the volume of the object, $\epsilon$ is its permittivity and $\epsilon_0$ is the permittivity of the surrounding medium.

There is a further correction term called the radiation loss term which makes $\alpha_e$ a complex quantity to respect energy conservation.